# How to link different spellings so one spelling references the other

Tags: google-sheets, xlookup

I have several different spelling of team names
ie. Los Angeles Lakers, LA Lakers, LAL etc

how can i group these together so when i use xlookup for example with Los Angeles Lakers it can pull data from LAL?

Ive tried to use wildcard combinations with xlookup but i think i need to group these spelling together but not sure how

more specific info:
sheet 1, A1, contains Los Angeles Lakers
sheet 2, A1:A100, this column contains team id's ie LAL

to pull in data Im reference sheet1 cell A1's value but need it to locate sheet2 LAL value

i think this has to be done on a seperate sheet otherwise i will have to hand code al the ids and names every day

ive seen a video where the user has a separate sheet with all the spelling variations linked?

any help or tutorial links would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)

```cpp
=FILTER(A2:A10,REGEXMATCH(B2:B10,"(?i)Los Angeles Lakers|LA Lakers|LAL"))
```

**Edit**

Assuming the list of options is in C2:C10,

```cpp
=FILTER(A2:A10,REGEXMATCH(B2:B10,"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,C2:C10)))
```

Comment: hi, This works however hand coding each line doesn't.. basically i have a list of 30 teams and 30 abbreviations that need to be linked.. cell locations change everyday